# POI Named Cell - Drop down in all the rows does not have all the values

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a strange issue when i create excel drop downs using Apache POI - Named Cell using below method.

```
public static void createHugeDropDown(XSSFWorkbook wb) {
        int i = 0;
        String sheetName = "LOOKUP";
        String colName = "COL1";
        String mainSheet = "sheet1";
        String[] strArray = new String[]{"10", "20", "30"};
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
        for (String str : strArray) {
            sheet.createRow(i++).createCell(0).setCellValue(str);
        }

        XSSFName namedCell = wb.createName();
        namedCell.setNameName(colName);
        String reference = sheetName + "!A1:A" + i;
        System.out.println(reference);
        namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);

        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet(mainSheet);
        int namedCellIndex = wb.getNameIndex(colName);
        namedCell = wb.getNameAt(namedCellIndex);
        AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(namedCell.getRefersToFormula());
        CellReference[] crefs = aref.getAllReferencedCells();
        System.out.println("Total Count --> " + crefs.length);
        for (int count = 0; count < crefs.length; count++) {
            Sheet s = wb.getSheet(crefs[count].getSheetName());
            Row r = sheet.getRow(crefs[count].getRow());
            Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[count].getCol());
            System.out.println("Cell Value" + c.getStringCellValue());
        }

        DataValidationConstraint constraint = null;
        DataValidation dataValidation = null;
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 100, 2, 2);
        DataValidationHelper validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet1);
        System.out.println(reference);

        constraint = validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint(reference);
        dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        wb.getSheet(mainSheet).addValidationData(dataValidation);
    }
```

This creates me a drop down. But the issue is 
1) I have 10,20 & 30 in first row
2) Have 20 & 30 alone in second row
3) Have 30 alone in third row.
4) Empty drop down from Fourth row till 100th row.

Can anybody point me the issue in the above code.

I want to display all the 3 values in the drop down in all the rows.

Comment: `String reference = sheetName + "!$A$1:$A$" + i` maybe relative references is the issue?

Comment: Wow.... It works perfectly the way it should. Thanks for your help.